# How to test/reactivate the DVI port of a monitor?

Tags: dvi

One of my monitors seems to have a "broken" DVI-Port with some strange behaviour:

- VGA works fine
- When plugging it in DVI, the nvidia-settings tool finds the monitor and the correct Hardware-Details, and i can configure the Monitor settings.
- After applying the settings the monitor switches between powersave mode and activating (without anything on display) back and forth.
- i tried different resolutions and refresh rates, which work fine on VGA, with the same result.
- Can a DVI Port break, with VGA still working?
- Wouldn't the monitor disappear from the nvidia-settings tool, when te port is really broken?

The DVI-Port of the graphics card is working just fine with other monitors, i tried the HDMI-Port with a HDMI->DVI cable which works with other monitors, but did not work with this one either.

The monitor is a "Medion MD30919PO S09".

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have the DVI and VGA cable connected at the same time. Push the input button on the monitor until it indicates it's on the DVI port. Change the resolution and refresh rate in Windows to 1024x768x16 bit color @ 60 hz refresh rate as this resolution is (for all intents and purposes) universally supported. Also, you mentioned plugging the computer in to other DVI displays... did you use the same cable for these or is it possible that the cable you're using with this monitor is a dud?

Comment: Its a Linux System. The Monitor worked some time ago, then it stopped working on the DVI-Port. The VGA Settings are 1280x1080@75.02Hz (Refresh rate autodetected by the nvidia driver). I tried different resolutions and refresh rates on the DVI port, without any success, i tried rebooting, which shows the BIOS screens on a different monitor, but not on that one. I just doubt, that a DVI port can break in a way, that the monitor is recognized correctly, but shows no image. The Onscreen Menu only works, when a signal is detected, so i cannot change any settings there when using DVI.

Comment: @allo the cable, check all the pins on both ends.

Comment: When you're saying you see BIOS screens on a different monitor, I'm assuming you mean at a different time, right? Do you have both monitors plugged in at the same time? If so, it's not uncommon for POST displays to only show on a "primary" monitor and the second monitor to remain inactive until something like extended desktop or mirroring is turned on in whatever application you're using to manage your displays.

Comment: I unplugged the cable from the working monitor, and plugged it into the other one. The pins seem okay, and is used two different cables (dvi-dvi, hdmi-dvi) with both monitors. One works without problems, the other one shows up in the nvidia tool, but shows no image in console/X/BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

probably you damaged the connectors backside of your monitor and it might likely need to get repaired or if it still has guarantee then turn it back for replacing or any further solutions. i think that the main problem is due to breaking of the solders on the monitor's circuit board  that need to be soldered again

Comment: It could be that the monitor has a defect, but narrowing it down to connector solder joints?

Comment: you know, you must be aware that when you want to connect dvi port whether into the monitor dvi in connector or into the graphic card dvi out, you have to make sure that the monitor and your pc are disconnected from the outlet, this is because due to the bare cover of dvi pin inside the tip of the port its possible that wrong static electricity enters the pin and then damages the broad of monitor or your graphic